# How to display next 7 days in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display the next 7 days dates using typescript, I know how to get the next 7th day but I don't no how to generate the list of 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
let weekDays = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  days.push( moment().add(i, 'days').format('dddd') )
}
console.log(weekDays);
```

Comment: if it works for you, please accept and upvote the answer.